# Getting a data type mismatch in criteria expression in vb.net when trying to update an integer field

Tags: vb.net

Not sure why I'm getting this error as I have a Message Box showing me the right output when the button is pressed but its not updating my Access database?

```
 Dim intAmount1 As Integer = 20
        Dim sum As Integer
        intBalance = intBalance - intAmount1
        sum = intBalance
        provider = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\Users\seand\Documents\IS2215_Database.accdb"
        connString = provider
        myConnection.ConnectionString = connString
        myConnection.Open()
        command = "update [tblAccountDetails] set [Account_Balance]=" & sum & " where [AccountID]=" & strAccountNo & ""
        Dim cmd As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand(command, myConnection)
        Try
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
            cmd.Dispose()
            myConnection.Close()

        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.Message)
        End Try
        MsgBox("Your New Balance Is: " & intBalance)
    End Sub
```

Comment: Use [OleDbCommand.Parameters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.oledb.oledbcommand.parameters). Use the `Add()` method, so you have specify the parameter type correctly; i.e., you'll have to specify whether `[AccountID]` is a string type of another, numeric, type. As of now, it's neither (starts in a way and ends in another).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most likely reason is that your AccountID column is text and you are passing a number. Just as you have to wrap a literal String in double quotes in VB code, so you have to wrap a literal string in single quotes in SQL code. If you do it properly and use parameters in your ADO.NET code when inserting values into SQL code then this is one of the many issues you can avoid.